# Reading a NFC Mifare card with NXP Reader Library

Tags: c, nfc, mifare

I'm trying to read the content of a Mifare Ultralight card using the NFC Reader Library.

I'm totally new with NFC and I'm using [this github repository](https://github.com/JohnMcLear/NXP-Raspberry-Pi-Card-Polling-Demo) to start.

The code in this repo allows to detect which type of card is detected (Mifare, Mifare ultralight ...) and read the UID of the card. I added this code in order to read the content of a Mifare ultralight card:

```
uint8_t bBufferReader[96];
memset(bBufferReader, '\0', 0x60);
PH_CHECK_SUCCESS_FCT(status, phalMful_Read(&alMful, 4, bBufferReader));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 96; i++){
   printf("%02X", bBufferReader[i]);
}
```

I have a card that contains the text "Hello world" and when I read it, the piece of code above print the following bytes:

```
0103A010440312D1010E5402667248650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So I'm reading some stuff out of my card, however there is no traces of a "Hello world"
text.

Probably missing something (might be a big something or, hopefully, a little something). Any help would be great !

#### Edit

So I made some good progress. Mifare ultralight contains 16 pages of 4 bytes, 0 - 3 are for internal usage (serial number, lock etc ...) and 4 - 15 are for user data. I can now read the content of my cards, however, just a few question remains:

I'm reading a card that contains an URL, www.google.com, here is what I got:

```
03 0F D1 01  -> Page 1, 4 bytes of non text data, not sure what it is 
0B 55 01 67  -> Page 2, 3 bytes of non text data, then 1 bytes for the "g"
6F 6F 67 6C  -> Page 3, 4 bytes for "oogl"
65 2E 63 6F  -> Page 4, 4 bytes for "e.co"
6D FE 00 00  -> Page 6, 1 byte  for "m", 1 byte for I don't know
00 00 00 00  -> Other pages are just empty
00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00
```

So I have got 7 bytes of data + my url, "google.com" + 1 byte `FE`

I can't find what are these 7 prefix bytes + this 1 trailing byte...

#### Edit again

Ok got it, it's the NDEF message format.

Comment: By the way, here is the open source driver I created (only read/write Mifare ultralight for now): https://github.com/robinmonjo/explore-nfc-board-driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is NDEF format!

```
03 NDEF Message
0F length
Record 1
D1 - MB, ME, SR, TNF=”NFC Forum well-known type”
01 Type length
0B Payload length
55 Type - “U”(Abbrivation for URL)  

67  6F 6F 67 6C  65 2E 63 6F 6D (google.com)

Record 2
FE Terminator NDEF
```

Comment: Thx answered myself but gonna accept this, still useful !